# R: Changes to dataframe variables from void function do not save

Tags: r, dataframe, function, loops

I have several variables in a dataframe that need to be updated. They all have the same prefix with a different suffix (see below), so I wrote a function to clean them all at once rather than go one-by-one. The function doesn't 'return' anything -- it only updates the specified variables in the dataframe. I am not sure I can specify a 'return' for this, since I am changing multiple variables (but not all of them) so I cannot 'return' the whole dataset nor any specific variable that is altered. From debugging, I can see that the variables all update within the function as expected, but after the function runs, the altered variables revert back to their previous values. Is there a way to make these changes to the dataset variables permanent?

```
# List of new variables for a data frame that will be updated    
screen$gender_man <- screen$gender_woman <- screen$gender_nonbin <- 
      screen$gender_trans <- screen$gender_addoption <- screen$gender_pnta <- NA

# Variable names for use within the function
    var_names <- as.character(expression(gender_man, gender_woman, gender_nonbin, 
      gender_trans, gender_addoption, gender_pnta))

# function designed to update newly created variables within dataframe
Multiple_CombQuest <- function(item_n, hcp_pre, chw_pre, name_vec) {
  for(i in 1:item_n) {
      hcp <- screen[,paste0(hcp_pre,i)]
      chw <- screen[,paste0(chw_pre,i)]
    
    combo <- ifelse(!is.na(hcp), hcp, chw)
    screen[,name_vec[i]] <- combo # sets the variables specified in line 1 to their new values
    
  }
print(screen$gender_man) # returns the updated version of the variable based on the above code (as expected)
}

Multiple_CombQuest(6, "Q23_", "Q55_", var_names)
print(screen$gender_man) # returns NA for all values rather than values updated in function (not expected)
```

Comment: R is a functional language, which means that functions should take an input and return an output. Only in rare circumstances is it a good idea to have a function which changes an object in the calling environment. You should write your function to take the data frame as one of its arguments and have the function return that data frame. That way, you would get the result you want by doing `screen <- Multiple_CombQuest(screen, 6, "Q23_", "Q55_", var_names)`